# Firebird: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

Tags: database-connection, firebird, firebird-embedded

I am creating a project windows runtime component(with c#), and I want to use embedded DB so I added Firebird-2.5.2.26540-0_x64_embed and .net component NETProvider-2.5.2-CF. Every time when I am performing any action on `FBcommand` and `FBConnection` i am getting error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll"

I can't use terget framework because its WinRT(c#) project...

Comment: You already asked in Firebird's list (lists actually). Why cross-posting?

Comment: @cincura.net I believe it was posted before you answered it on the Firebird .NET mailinglist.

Answer (score 1):

Note this answer is actually by [@cincura.net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092245/cincura-net) on the Firebird .NET mailinglist. I am just posting it here for completeness:

> The ADO.NET stack is not available in WinRT, hence you cannot use any
>   database access. The CF version didn't helped either.

See [How should a Windows 8 Metro Application connect to a central database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681842/how-should-a-windows-8-metro-application-connect-to-a-central-database) and [How might a Windows 8 Metro app handle back end database access?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/how-might-a-windows-8-metro-app-handle-back-end-database-access) for potential solutions.